# How to create custom row in Listview for only selected rows?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using simple adapter for listlist view:

```
        //adapter for list
    simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            this,
            Splash.scriptList,
            R.layout.mytextview,
            new String[] {"value","key"},
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2 });
```

i need that only specific rows will be in different color , (maybe add icon to them).

for example if i have 10 items in row, i need that rows 3,5,6 will be displayed in different style.

How can i do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777272/android-listview-with-different-layout-for-each-row?rq=1

Comment: you can use a Boolean and change its value each time row gets generated and when its true change background of the` textview` and when its false don't do anything.